# react - handling promise without "ReduxPromise"

Tags: reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I'm trying to handle a promise without using "ReduxPromise".

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>{this.props.weatherData.then(response => {return response.data.city.name})}</div>
    </div>
);
```

But I get this error :

```
bundle.js:1212 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).
```

If I `console.log(response.data.city.name)`, I do get a resulted string.

With ReduxPromise, I just have to do this :

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
```

Then I only have to return this in the component :

```
<div>{this.props.weatherData.data.city.name}</div>
```

But I want to do it WITHOUT ReduxPromise

Without ReduxPromise, `this.props.weatherData` IS a promise. How do I handle this in the component ?

Doing this below does an infinite loop :

```
render(){
    if (!this.props.weatherData) {
        return <div></div>
    };

    this.props.weatherData.then(response => {
        this.setState({ weatherData: response.data });
        console.log(this.state.weatherData.city.name);
    });
```

City name outputted infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to render the return value of this.props.weatherData.then(...) in the jsx, which would be a promise, which is what the error message is telling you. Instead, fetch the data, put it in state, and render based off of that state.

Example:

```
class WeatherDataComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weatherData: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.weatherData.then(response => {
      this.setState({ weatherData: response.data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.weatherData) {
      return null 
    }
    return (
      <div>{this.state.weatherData.city.name}</div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null`

Comment: `this.props.weatherData` doesn't exist when calling componentDidMount

Comment: props.weatherData is just a function to fetch the weatherData, right? If so, why doesn't it exist on mount? If for some reason it doesn't and can't, you would have to set up a componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method to look for props.weatherData to exist, at which point you can trigger the fetch. Little odd that it doesn't exist though, since you should have gotten the same error when you were calling this.props.weatherData in render.

Comment: weatherData is part of the state. It's value is setup by an action creator that triggers the reducer that sets up the weatherData value. I'm mapping it to props with mapStateToProps.  As I said, it works with "ReduxPromise". I just have to render this: `<div>{this.props.weatherData.data.city.name}</div>` .   But I'm trying the same WITHOUT "ReduxPromise". (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TLadd, I needed a lifecycle method, namely `componentWillReceiveProps` :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.weatherData) {
        return;
    };  
    nextProps.weatherData.then(response => {
            this.setState({ city: response.data.city.name });
    });
}
```

Then :

```
render(){
    if (!this.props.weatherData) {
        return <div></div>
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.city}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And for the infinite loop, I'm pretty it's because of this : 
`setState` causes the component to re-render, then the `.then` callback is called, so `setState` again, then re-render, etc.